# Modifying Slider's ToolTip

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I'd like to make my own style and content of the `ToolTip` that shows when you hover the mouse over a Slider in a Windows Store App. How can I do this?

e.g. I'm creating a movie player and i'd like to format value of Slider to HH:MM:SS instead of "SSSSS"

Comment: You are stuck on the olden ways of UI programming.  Store apps are operated by the user's finger.  Touch screens cannot detect a hover.

Comment: hmm... unfortunately i think that on my computer there's still outmoded cursor, and Slider is responding for PointerEntered/Exited events...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write converter for ThumbToolTipValueConverter of Slider